# Having trouble decoding seq2seq predicitions

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a decoder for the a seq2seq model I have.
So far what I have is:

```
dec_op_reshaped = tf.reshape(decoder_outputs, [-1, state_size])
logits = tf.matmul(dec_op_reshaped, V) + bo
feed_dict = {
            self.xs_ : query,
            self.dec_inputs_length_ : [query.shape[-1]*2], # this bothers me!
            self.keep_prob_ : 1.
            }
translated_arr = self._sess.run(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), axis=1), feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

I do not know what I've been doing wrong, but everytime a query is passed, it returns an array of zeroes instead of idx2w (what's expected).

EDIT:
I am so sorry. Sometimes it's right in front of you and you miss it.
The state-size was 0 - hence the problem.

Comment: why that part is bothering you? also, mention what is idx2w in your code snippet?

Comment: idx2w is simply the expected array. For eg - [24, 65, 73, 2]
Instead I get - [0, 0, 0, 0]